# Nginx: lag when loading static content

Tags: linux, centos, nginx

I have a `sphinx` doc with `Read the docs` theme on Nginx. Something like that:

```
location ^~ /docs {
    alias /path/to/docs/build/html/;
    index index.html;
    gzip  on;
}
```

There is a microlag when page loading from cache(< 1s): html text without css styling. With `add_header Cache-Control no-cache;` this problem dissappears. My doc's pages are not as big as *docs.readthedocs.org*. Docs is built by *python 3.6*, all packages from *pypi*.

[image: download logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When css files load before js files, everything is ok. But sphinx-builder puts *css includes* after *js includes*. So i wrote script to fix that:

```bsh
for file in build/html/*html; do
    links=$(sed -n '/.*rel=\"stylesheet\"/p' $file)
    sed -i "/.*rel=\"stylesheet\"/d" $file
    awk -v line="$links" "1;/.*<title>/{ print line}" $file > $file.tmp
    mv $file.tmp $file
    echo $file updated 
done
```